# Depending on springProfiles[dev, stg, prod] in logback-spring.xml , how to activate corresponding spring profile passed in command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my application-properteis, i have set spring.profiles.active=dev, but when i pass from command line via gradle clean -Dspring.profiles.active=stg build, it is taking by default dev profile only. how ot overwrite the default value set in application.properteis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below configuration using profile. Active profiles can be set using command line argument -Dspring.profiles.active="abc". For multiple profiles, you can include profile names comma separated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appender name="rootappender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <springProfile name="abc">
      <file>${LOG_ROOT}/abc.log</file>
   </springProfile>
   <springProfile name="xyz">
      <file>${LOG_ROOT}/xyz.log</file>
   </springProfile>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element 
                or else the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
      <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/system_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
   </triggeringPolicy>
   <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Is there any changes required in java code, if i run with gradle -Dspring.profiles.active=abc, will it pick up. i want to run it using gradle with spring boot. please clarify

Comment: Please help me how to overwrite the value set in application.properteis file. In my application.propeties file i have spring.profiles.active="dev", but when i pass from command line gradle -Dspring.profiles.active="stg" build it is not taking latest profile [stg] which i am passing. please guide me

Comment: 1. Build a jar using maven/graddle 2. Run this using Java command line utility java -cp . -jar <your jar name> --Dspring.profiles.active="abc". It should work if not remove the entries from application.properties.

Comment: Sir, i did the instructions which you told, but when i run java -cp . -jar ./build/libs/api-0.0.1.jar -Dspring.profiles.active="dev", the spring banner is coming up and returning the terminal. but actually i want to run docker-compose up after the gradle buildTask. so please guide a bit more.

Comment: Below links might help you https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-docker-example/    https://www.baeldung.com/dockerizing-spring-boot-application    In docker command you can specify the jar startup command there you should put the arguments.

Comment: Can we override the spring.profiles.active value set in application.properties, using gradle config and command. ?? please guide a bit. I am very new to it. Whenever i run with gradle command -Dprofiles.active="stg" , it is taking what i set in application.properties. I have set as spring.profiles.active=dev in properties file.

Comment: Remove the entry from your application.properties.

Comment: Also command line agrument will be -Dspring.profiles.active="stg"

Comment: After removing the entry from application.properties file and passing as gradle clean buildDocker -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" , i am not able to see any logs except spring banner. how do i debug. is there any config miss ??

Comment: specify logging level in application.properties like logging.level.org.springframework=INFO, check the URL https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: No sir. i specified logging.level.org.springframework=info in application.properties and then ran gradle -Dprofiles.active="dev" taskName, then docker-compose up. I am not able to see any logs. I think this is not the right way.

Comment: -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" not -Dprofiles.active="dev".

Comment: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev. I gave but not working. I want to find out a way how to attach run time arguments to jar via docker file. so that it will take up and run.

Comment: ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar --spring.config.location=$CONFIG_LOCATION -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"] should be the command

Comment: Check the URLs https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/  https://www.baeldung.com/dockerizing-spring-boot-application

Comment: thank you, done this before and was able to load the respective loggs depending on kind of environment. Thanks for your support. Could you please guide me or give me links of spring boot, docker . Atleast worth watching kind of videos.